# Using Interactive Broker's C#API to access fundamental data

Tags: interactive-brokers

I had been trying to use the C#API to access HOng Kong Stock Fundamental Data.
Some Background:

I tried the same program for accessing Hong Kong Stock market data and it is working, as follow:

```
namespace IB_Real_time_Console_CS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Samples.EWrapperImpl ibClient = new Samples.EWrapperImpl();
            ibClient.ClientSocket.eConnect("", 7496, 0);
            var reader = new EReader(ibClient.ClientSocket, ibClient.Signal);
            reader.Start();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (ibClient.ClientSocket.IsConnected())
                {
                    ibClient.Signal.waitForSignal();
                    reader.processMsgs();
                }
            })
            { IsBackground = true }.Start();
            while (ibClient.NextOrderId <= 0) { }

            Contract contract = new Contract();
            contract.Symbol = "700";
            contract.SecType = "STK";
            contract.Exchange = "SEHK";
            contract.Currency = "HKD";

            List<TagValue> mktDataOptions = new List<TagValue>();
ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contract, "", true, false, mktDataOptions);

            // Pause so we can view the output
            Console.ReadKey();

            ibClient.ClientSocket.cancelMktData(1);
            ibClient.ClientSocket.eDisconnect();


        }   //end Main
    }       //end class Program
}           //end namespace IB_Real_time_console_cs
```

My aim is to access fundamental data. So I change this line of code:
`ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contract, "", true, false, mktDataOptions);`

into this:
`ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contract, "258", true, false, mktDataOptions);`

However I run into the following errors:

```
Error ID:-1 code:2104: Msg: Market data farm connection is OK:hfarm
Error ID:-1 code:2104: Msg: Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
Error ID:-1 code:2104: Msg: Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
Error ID:-1 code:2104: Msg: Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm

Error ID:-1 code:2106: Msg: HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds.us
Error ID:-1 code:2106: Msg: HMDS data farm connection is OK:hkhmds
Error ID:-1 code:2106: Msg: HMDS data farm connection is OK:fundfarm
Error ID:-1 code:2106: Msg: HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
```

> Error ID:1, code 321, Msg:Error validating request:-'bo': cause-snapshot market data subscription is not applicable to generic ticks

```
Error ID:-1 code 2108, Msg: Market data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.usfuture
Error ID:-1 code 2108, Msg: Market data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.usfuture
Error ID:-1 code 2108, Msg: Market data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.cashfarm
Error ID:-1 code 2108, Msg: Market data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.cashfarm
```

Can anyabody point out what's wrong with this change of code?
Alternatively, how can fundamental data be accessed?
Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

Read your errors, most of them are just information about the connection, the one I highlighted tells you the problem.  You're asking for a snapshot and you're not allowed.  The 4th arg is `bool snapshot`, set this to false.

```
void reqMktData (   int     tickerId,
    Contract    contract,
    string  genericTickList,
    bool    snapshot,
    bool    regulatorySnaphsot,
    List< TagValue >    mktDataOptions 
)
```

`ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contract, "258", false, false, mktDataOptions);`

Comment: Thank you very much Brian...I just changed it to 'false' and it works!! Bravo!!